# SharePoint based form submit to C# app that creates Powerpoint 2007 presentation for user download

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, powerpoint, office-interop

I have Written a simple console program (in C#) that generates a PowerPoint Presentation but i need to be able to have objects (text,pictures etc) set via an asp.net form based on a SharePoint page,  Currently this saves a presentation anywhere i tell it too, but i require it to output as a user download from SharePoint.  I'm looking for any pointers on how to go about doing such a thing.  I understand the use of Forms and Requesting Parameters etc but not sure on how to go about having the program run server side and output a downloadable file.

Any Help, greatly appreciated.

I would post some code but i am very new to ASP so this is very much research into how i am to go about doing such a thing.  As far as i can see ill have to have the forms populated from a SharePoint list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly on your asp.net WebApp.
Just like this:

```
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Pos Venda");

            #region tabelaPrincipal

            worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 9].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 9].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(149, 179, 215));
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 9].Style.Border.BorderAround(OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Medium, System.Drawing.Color.Black);

            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "N. O.S.";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "DATA";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "TECNICO";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "TEMPO";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "ATIVIDADE";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 6].Value = "COMO";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 7].Value = "EMPRESA";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 8].Value = "VALOR";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 9].Value = "SITUACAO";
            package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Relatório de Pós Venda";
            package.Workbook.Properties.Author = "SGP";
            package.Workbook.Properties.Company = "Libracom Automação Industrial Ltda.";

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", "Relatorio" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") + ".xlsx"));
            Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.SuppressContent = true;
            ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            Response.End();
```

@edit: using EPPlus DLL. http://epplus.codeplex.com/